# How to prove that this complex series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

In Conway's book, "Functions of one complex variable", page 33 ex. 7., ask for the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)},\ \ \ \text{when   } z=i.$$ I know that if converges, it must be to a real number, because $i^{n(n+1)}$ is always $1$ or $-1$ but I don't know how exactly proves this. Any help would be fine.

Comment: Maybe begin by figuring out the pattern for $(-1)^n i^{n(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write out the first few terms of $(-1)^ni^{n(n+1)}$, you'll find the sequence is of the form $1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,\dotsc$, and you can prove that this pattern repeats. Hence you can write the summation as
$$ 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \left( \frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k+1} \right) $$
(I haven't changed the order of the terms, so this is fine), and then the alternating series test applies.

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think you got the wrong summation, since yours begins with $1-(1/2+1/3)+(1/3+1/4)$, whereas it should begin $1-1/2-1/3+1/4$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Ah yes, need to make a slight tweak there...